# How do I simplify this Python for loop?

Tags: python, loops

I'm relatively new to Python and I was wondering how I could simplify the following code any further. The code determines whether a number, `n`, is a power of `2` by using a `for loop`.

```
def is_power(n):
    if n <= 2:
        return True
    for i in range(3, n):
        if i * i == n:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Do you mean "is a square"? `i * i` tests whether a number is a square. Power of two is a different thing (2^n).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an oversimplification :)

```
def is_power_of_two(n):
    return n and not (n & (n - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it by checking if the root square is an integer value :

```
def is_power(n):
    return True if n**(1/2) == int(n**(1/2)) else False
```